# Using (-webkit-)backdrop-filter on transparant header

Tags: css, image

I would like to apply a backdrop filter using (-webkit-)backdrop-filter on a transparent header whose text is partly see-through (using rgba). Doing this, however, applies the filter to the text's (square) background instead of applying it to the backdrop behind just the text itself.

You can find the code I'm currently using below.

Remember to link `background-image: url("images.png");` to an actual image if you would like to demo this code. Also keep in mind that `backdrop-filter` is only available on Edge, Chrome (version 76 and onwards, earlier versions when enabling the flag) and Safari (using the -webkit- vendor prefix).

As you can see, I'm also using `content` to add append extra text to the header depending on screen size. Though the answer doesn't necessarily have to work in conjunction with this, it would be appreciated.

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Drake</h1>
</div>

<style>
#header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("images.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

#header h1 {
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px) saturate(130%) brightness(300%);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  font-size: calc(75px + 5vw);
  margin: 0;
}

#header h1:after {
  content: " Dragon";
  white-space: pre;
}

@media (max-width:750px) {
  #header h1:after {
    content: " D.";
    white-space: pre;
  }
}

@media (max-width:450px) {
  #header h1:after {
    content: none;
    white-space: pre;
  }
}
</style>
```

The effect I'm trying to achieve can be seen on Apple's website. More specifically, the page about their upcoming "Arcade" service. On this page, the subheader has a dynamic blur effect.

https://i.imgur.com/aRChGko.png (https://www.apple.com/apple-arcade/)

The code I am using, on the other hand, does not achieve this nice blur effect. Instead of blurring just the text itself, it also blur the background of the text.

https://i.imgur.com/wfS5vNQ.png (https://jsfiddle.net/pfe39avr/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris Coyier from CSS-Tricks has written up an article on how to do this: https://css-tricks.com/a-glassy-and-classy-text-effect/. Below is an example.

```html
<video src="https://css-tricks-post-videos.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Universe%20-%2013100.mp4" controls muted autoplay loop></video>

<h1 class="headline">
  <span class="visually-hidden">Awesome Headline</span>
  <svg aria-hidden="true" id="lockup-headline-mask" class="headline lockup-headline-mask visually-hidden">
    <clipPath id="lockup-headline-mask-path">
      <text dominant-baseline="hanging" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="0em" dy="0.125em">Awesome Headline</text>
    </clipPath>
  </svg>
</h1>

<style>
video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}
.headline {
  width: 100%;
  font: 8vw system-ui, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  height: 150px;
}
@supports (backdrop-filter: blur(12px)) {
  .visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
  }
  h1 {
    backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
    background: rgba(white, 0.2);
    clip-path: url(#lockup-headline-mask-path);
  }
}
</style>
```